# Credentials to postgresql database on Heroku seems to have been changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have a Ruby on Rails app with a posgresql database running on Heroku.  In my `config/database.yml` file, I have the following entry

```
production: &deploy
  encoding: utf8
  min_messages: warning
  pool: <%= [Integer(ENV.fetch("MAX_THREADS", 5)), Integer(ENV.fetch("DB_POOL", 5))].max %>
  timeout: 5000
  url:  <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_URL", "") %>
```

so I am expecting Heroku to handle the database setup and credentials.

The app has been operating successfully for several years. Since Heroku database maintenance, when I try to run the app, I get an error message `FATAL:  password authentication failed for user: "xyz"`.  If I do `heroku config` the DATABASE_URL is of the form `postgres://xyz:some_long_hash`, which seems to imply that `xyz` is the correct username.

However if I go into heroku web portal, I can view the database credentials, the listed user name is not `xyz` but some other user name, and there is a very long password.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You can delete `url:  <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_URL", "") %>` as it's completely superfluous. Rails will merge  `DATABASE_URL` with the setting from the config file anyways and it takes preceedence. I don't get why people keep adding this anyways. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database

Comment: max, you are correct. The only justification I have seen is provides reminder that the url is stored in 'DATABASE_URL`, but I think I would be better just to use a comment for this reminder.   Note my answer to the question.  I will be deleting this comment when you have had a chance to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this article from [Heroku Support](https://help.heroku.com/8F4AXAOP/why-am-i-seeing-fatal-role-xxx-is-not-permitted-to-log-in-error-when-trying-to-connect-to-a-heroku-postgres-database-hobby-mini-basic-tier), I needed to rotate the credentials manually. I did this with

```
heroku pg:credentials:rotate
```

which worked.

Evidently with with the Hobby/Mini/Tier, when Heroku does maintenance, this problem can occur. You can check if the credentials are valid with

```
pg:credentials:url -a <appname>
```

Based on a comment by max, I will be deleting from `config/database.yml` the line

```
  url:  <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_URL", "") %>
```

and replacing it with a comment to the effect that heroku chooses the url and stores it as config variable `DATABASE_URL`.